# Javascript not waiting for For loop. Object values not changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, for-loop

I have a call to MongoDB in Node.js. The call returns a list of users, each with a variety of fields such as name, email, role. One of the fields returned is `_id`. I want a this field without the underscore when I send the data back to the frontend of my app, so I've created a for loop to iterate the list and add the new key. See below:

```
//find all users
User.find({}).select("_id name email locked logins role created lastLogin").exec(function(err, users) {

  //error fetching users
  if (err) throw err;

  //add new id key
  for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    users[i].id = users[i]._id;
  }

  //send user list
  res.send(users);

});
```

Now my problem is that the `res.send(users)` doesn't seem to be sending the altered version, just the original data. If I put the following in the `for loop`:

```
for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
  users[i].id = users[i]._id;
  console.log(users[i].id);
}
```

Then I get the new fields logged. However, if I do a `console.log(users)` outside and after the for loop, I get the original unchanged data. It's like it's executing the `for loop`, then doing the `res.send` before the `for loop` has done it's thing.

Comment: If you're using Mongoose, the documents will already have a [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)-only [`id` property](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id). You'll probably have to either [disable its definition](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) in the `Schema` or [retrieve plain objects](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) of each document to set it yourself.

Comment: Where are you doing the console.log - show it in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe mongoose is preventing you from setting `id` since it isn't defined in your `User` model. Add a field `id` with the value `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` in your model if you want this to work.

Comment: This is an even better solution! Thanks, I was wondering how to change it in the database itself, it's a much better way to do it.

Comment: Consider creating a new object and passing that object in ```res.send()```.  I don't believe you need to be creating duplicate data just to send data back in a response.

Comment: @Duane13 Thanks I just realised that would be possible too, now I know it's an issue with the User schema.

Comment: No problem. Remember to select it as the correct answer if it ended up working :)